# Dual channel wireless microphone

Tags: wireless

Is there any option for a high quality dual channel wireless microphone system for under $1000?  I would like to have one receiver box that is capable of receiving feed from both a lavalier and a handheld (or second lavaleir) that I could mix independently.

I am partial to Shure and Sennheiser but if another brand is recommended I will give it consideration. Just need realiability in the realm of no drop out/weak signal. Also not a big fan of AudioTechnica.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you looking for a portable solution or a stationary one? The SRa and SRb from Lectrosonics are the choiced wireless for the location guys who want such a function but definitely not under $1000.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Stock_In+stock&ci=15708&N=3992462050+4293345056+4291628428+4291606550+4291226455+4291223026

I don't know why you are ruling out AudioTechnica though.  I'm not a huge fan of their mics, but if you get lav packs and use different mics, they can get pretty good quality for the transmitter itself.

Really your best bet though is just looking through highly reviewed gear on B&H and similar that is in your price range and pick accordingly.  Lots of gear should be able to handle what you are working with and nobody is going to have worked with all of it to give you a definitive best option in your price range for your environment.